# winbind needs to be restarded after boot

Tags: samba, centos6, winbind

Environment: Centos 6.6 Samba 3.6.23-12.el6

I have succesfully connected the server to an Active Directory Domain and I have configured it as a Samba File Server. It works fine as long as I reboot, after the normal boot I have to restart the winbind otherwise no one can access the network shares.
If I try to access the server to Active Directory via wbinfo -u I get no results and even errors. After restarting winbind everything is ok.

What could be the problem?

**UPDATE**: the solution seems to be to set the start of winbind after all other services. I honestly do not know, however, give me an explanation, so I remain alerted.